# Sluggish GUI on Ubuntu 18.04 running xfce4

Tags: 18.04, xfce

I'm rather new to using Linux systems. I'm having a problem currently with a server machine on Ubuntu 18.04 running xfce4.

I'm able to access the server's desktop using Windows RDP, but there's an incredible delay using the GUI. I don't believe the machine specs are the issue as I'm running a Xeon E3-1425v2 @ 3.4GHz with 32GB DDR3 1333Mhz.

I'm no expert, but I think I need to install something to reduce the lag. Can anyone provide me some advice?

Comment: Servers are often equipped with a rudimentary graphics chip, because you are expected to interact with it using a text mode interface. Another problem could be that you have a more powerful graphics chip or card, but you need a proprieary driver to take full advantage of it. So please specify the brand name and model of the graphics chip/card in order to help us help you.

Comment: It's this:
Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: Can you use the built-in graphics directly to a monitor? In that case, is the graphics more responsive than remotely via Windows RDP? Or can you only log in remotely? What local network is there: wired or wifi? speed?

Comment: The server can only be accessed remotely. It's a wired network, 500Mbp/s up.

Comment: Generally, a graphical desktop and programs with a graphical user interface are much slower via remote access compared to direct access. An alternative might be to connect via `ssh -X` and view only a single window instead of the whole desktop environment. And several (most?) tasks can be run via text mode tools in a terminal window (using plain `ssh`). This should make things more responsive.